# How to connect to Remote Mysql server that requires SSH?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, ftp

Not sure this is the place to ask this, but I am trying to connect to a server which I have full access to. I can login to the phpMyAdmin from the web, but when I try to connect to it from C#, it doesn't work. It shows the following error in particular:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Here's the connection string I'm using:

```
string mycon = "server=someIP;port=3306;uid=user;pwd=pwd;database=mydb;Convert Zero Datetime=True";
```

I think this is because the server requires SSH. Is there any way I can disable SSH requirement for the connection?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the firewall isn't blocking port 3306? Go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and make sure the port is open to public.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get. When I test it for both the server and my IP, it shows that the port is closed. So how come I am able to access it via phpmyadmin?

Comment: Oh, wait, the server is actually on an Intranet, so it won't be visible from online servers. Can I check this manually? On testing for listening ports, I can see the port there but I'm not sure it's open... etc

Comment: `telnet someIP 3306`  If you get a connection (even though you can't do anything) the port is open.  connect failed means it's closed.

Comment: Hmm, says `unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: @rtuner Then it might be a firewall issue. Do you have access to the host machine?

Comment: yes, I have access to both machines.

Comment: try [this to open the port](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall) on the host machine.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Problem is, I can't do that for every user i.e. I can't configure the machine of everyone I install the app on.

Comment: You need the port to be open on the server, it shouldn't matter on the client.

Comment: @rtuner As I said in the comment, you need to open the port on the host machine (i.e. the machine on which MySql exists).

Comment: So how can I open the port, I just tried: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT` but still can't connect

Comment: @rtuner http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall. Follow the steps to add an Inbound Rule to Windows Firewall.

Comment: That is for the client PC, but I want to do the opening on the server PC.

Comment: @rtuner Do this on the server PC!

Comment: Sorry, the server PC is actually linux

Comment: Thanks everyone, I finally resolved it by changing mysql config

Answer (score 1):

If port 3306 is closed, you won't be able to connect from a remote host. PHPmyadmin works because it is running on the same machine as the mysql server (I assume) so it is not connecting from a remote host. You need to either open port 3306 and configure mysql to listen to port 3306, or you mention that you have ssh, which opens up another option.

If you aren't able to open 3306 to the general public, you could create an ssh tunnel to the server that forwards 3306 on the mysql server to some port on your local machine (like 3307), then configure C# to connect to that local port.

```
string mycon = "server=localhost;port=3307;uid=user;pwd=pwd;database=mydb;Convert Zero Datetime=True";
```

Here's an example of how to forward a port with putty.
http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

Also, the easiest way to check for open ports on an ip is a port scanner like nmap. I'm assuming you're on windows since you're using C#.
There is windows gui client here: http://nmap.org/zenmap/

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by changing the mysql configuration in my.cnf

It was previously:

> ## bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1

and I changed it to

> ## bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0

Restart mysql service, and everything's fine :)